# Get data from two MySQL tables and ORDER based on the data from the two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am lost trying to join two tables together and then returning the results ordered by columns in both tables. Here is the query i have that does not return any rows:

```
SELECT category.name,
       client.name,
       client.member
FROM   `category`,
       `client`
       INNER JOIN `client`
               ON client.name = category.name
WHERE  catdesc = '$info'
ORDER  BY client.member,
          category.name ASC
```

What I want to return with this query:

I want a list of names (name is common to both tables) that have a certain 'catdesc' ORDERED

FIRST: by members sorted by name ASC

THEN

SECOND: after the members, the non-members sorted by name ASC.

Comment: why are you joining 2 times to `client` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three table references in your query, at least one of the references to the `client` table needs to be given an alias, otherwise, you are going to have an "ambiguous column" error.

Don't mix the old-school "comma" join operator with the `JOIN` keyword. Best practice is to qualify all column references, even if they aren't ambiguous.

Your current query text is equivalent to:

```
SELECT category.name
     , client.name
     , client.member
  FROM `category`
  JOIN `client`
  JOIN `client` 
    ON client.name = category.name
 WHERE catdesc ='$info' 
ORDER BY client.member, category.name ASC
```

Which we'd expect to throw an error. We'd really expect to see something more like:

```
SELECT category.name
     , client.name
     , client.member
  FROM `category`
  JOIN `client`
    ON client.name = category.name
 WHERE category.catdesc = '$info'
 ORDER
    BY client.member
     , category.name
```

Answer (score 3):

Your join query is not correct you have

```
SELECT 
category.name, 
client.name, 
client.member 
FROM `category`,
`client` <----- here is the issue
INNER JOIN `client` ON client.name = category.name 
WHERE catdesc ='$info' 
ORDER BY client.member, category.name ASC
```

This should be

```
SELECT 
category.name, 
client.name, 
client.member 
FROM `category`
INNER JOIN `client` ON client.name = category.name 
WHERE catdesc ='$info' 
ORDER BY client.member, category.name ASC
```

Comment: I removed 'client' in the FROM portion of my statement but it still does not return any rows. Before now, I was only pulling the names without trying to sort by member so this query does return rows:`SELECT name FROM 'category' WHERE catdesc = '$info' ORDER BY name asc`

Comment: can u echo the query and try it directly on mysql and see if u get something ? since there is a condition `WHERE catdesc ='$info'` and due to it if no matching data found then will return 0 rows and more over joining is done on  `client.name = category.name` so make sure the joining tables have matching data.

Comment: or post the tables with some data in www.sqlfiddle.com so that I can create a live example for u.